Происхождение семантик прил. 'круглый', отличных от семантики "имеющий форму круга или шара"
Прил. 'круглый' имеет семантики, отличные от семантики "имеющий форму круга или шара".
Примеры:

полный, целый
в полной мере обладающий какими-либо свойствами
cчитаемый, вычисленный без дробных, мелких единиц счёта

Каково происхождение таких семантик?

Он круглый идиот. // С какой стороны не посмотри он идиот
Он квадратный идиот. // С какой то стороны идиот, а с какой то стороны не так уж и понятно.

